# Not sure what kind of algorithm this problem requires / what data structure (Printer Queue problem)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This is pretty much a printer queue problem.

Sample input:

```
6 0
1 1 9 1 1 1
```

First line = two numbers, first is the number of printer jobs, second is the position of your job in the queue

Second line = the priority of each job. First number listed is the priority of the first job, and so forth. The larger the number, the higher the priority.

The printer runs this loop indefinitely:

1. Read the job J at the head of the queue.
2. If there's another job in the queue with a higher priority than J, move J to the end of the queue.
3. Otherwise, execute job J (which takes 1 minute to complete) and remove it from the queue.

Output the amount of minutes until the printer has completed your job.

The problem is that position matters. So, as you can see in the test case, your job is first in the queue, which means it'd get moved to the rear because it's not the highest priority, then the second job would get moved to the rear as well, and your job would finish printing after 5 minutes.

I'm thinking a LinkedList would be best for this, but you'd have to keep track of highest priority, which is dynamically altered. The problem with a PriorityQueue is that elements are inserted based on some Comparator, whereas the initial ordering of my structure would be based on position. Also, you can't add to the rear of a PriorityQueue.

So, I'm kinda stuck here in terms of knowing which structure to use, or whether this problem involves any structure at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188410/discussion-on-question-by-user10729497-not-sure-what-kind-of-algorithm-this-prob).

Comment: I have clarified my answer and incorporated your example. I realize the previous description was a bit fast. Will you have a look and let me know if it is not clear or if it does not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I wrote that @MinosIllyrien answer was correct, but that's not the case. However, I think I can fix my answer. Feel free to comment if you think I failed.**

Here's my own explanation:

Imagine you have three categories of people:

- more important than you (MITY),
- as important as you (AIAY),
- less important than you (LITY).

In a fair world, what happens? First, the MITY pass, then the AIAY that where before you in the queue pass, and it's your turn (no matter how many LITY are there: let's be fair, but not to much).

But in your world, every time a MITY passes, he/she changes the order of the AIAYs. That doesn't matter until the last MITY passes. If he/she was before you, no problem. But if he/she was behind you, you and all the AIAY before him/her are moved to the rear. So the AIAY **behind** this one are before you, and the AIAY that where before you are still before you. Thus, the only AIAY that remain after you are the ones between you and the last MITY.

**EDIT: The issue is the order of the MITY: they are not ordered by position (the issue in MinosIllyrien answer) but *by priority and* by position. The section above was not flawed and remains unchanged.**

If you need to output the sorted jobs, you don't either need a specific data structure. Here's an algorithm with a simple linked list (or two array lists: one to store the jobs, one to mark the executed jobs)

Assuming the list of jobs is not empty.

1. let Ps = ordered set of priorities, from maximum to minimum
2. let last_pos = 0
3. let P = Ps.pop() and start_pos = last_pos
4. execute (and remove) all jobs with the priority P, from start_pos to last_pos of P (with an rewind from end to start)
5. if Ps is not empty, back to 3, else end.

The time complexity is O(n log n) for step 1, then O(n) for every P in Ps, that is O(n log n + n * Ps.size). If you know the boundaries of priorities, step 1 is O(n) only with a bucket sort and thus the whole sequence has a O(n * Ps.size) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to simulate the printer's behavior, I think the right approach is to use a linked-list (or an array plus an integer to track your current position as you repeatedly loop through it) *plus* a priority-queue. Whenever you find that the value at the head of the linked-list matches the top value on the priority queue, you remove it from both. This approach requires worst-case *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time.

But if you just want to find the number of minutes, you can do that in worst-case *O*(*n* log *m*) time, where *n* is the total number of jobs and *m* is the number of distinct priorities. (*m* ≤ *n*, so that is also worst-case *O*(*n* log *n*) time.) Here's one way:

1. Build a `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` mapping from each priority-value to the list of job-queue-indices having that priority.

   - This requires *O*(*n* log *m*) time, where *m* is the number of distinct priorities in the queue.
   - As a small optimization, we can skip any priority-values that are less than that of the job of interest.
2. Initialize `int lastPos = -1` and `int numJobsCompleted = 0`.
3. Iterate over the values in the mapping (= the lists of job-queue-indices), starting at the greatest priority-value and working down toward the priority-value of the job we're interested in. For each list of indices, find the greatest job-queue-index (= list-element) that's less than `lastPos`, if there is one; otherwise, take the greatest job-queue-index (= list-element). In either case, update `lastPos` to that job-queue-index, and update `numJobsCompleted` to add the size of the list of job-queue-indices.

   - The idea here is that, when we've examined all priorities greater than or equal to a certain value, `lastPos` points to the index of the latest-completed item in the job queue; so that the we process jobs of the next priority starting at index `lastPos+1` and ending at index `lastPos-1` (wrapping around at *n*, of course).
   - This requires worst-case *O*(*n*) if we use linear search on the array-lists.
   - As a small optimization, we can use binary search on the array-lists.
   - As a small optimization, we can start by scanning for the least priority-value that's greater than or equal to the priority-value of the job we're interested in and that has exactly one job-queue-index in its array-list. Pro
4. When we reach the priority-value of the job we're interested in, we just need to find the number of job-indices between `lastPos` and the index of the job we're interested in, and update `numJobsCompleted` accordingly. This can be done with either linear search — worst-case *O*(*n*) — or binary search — worst-case *O*(log *n*).

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong - I have written why in the bottom:

[[Run through the list. Until your index, count every element with the same priority or higher than yours as one. After your index, count only elements with strictly higher priority than your element as one until the last index with a higher priority. After that index, resume counting all elements with the same priority as yours as one. This gives you the number of elements that will be printed before your element, so add one minute for your own element.

I hope this helps.

EDIT:

To clarify: Let us rename all elements in the queue according to their priority. l is lower, e is equal, and h is higher. w is the wanted document. The sequence in the questions would then be:

```
w e h e e e
```

We start by counting the number of *e*'s and *h*'s before *w*, since these will be printed before *w*. (The e's are moved to the back of the queue before *w*, and the *h*'s are treated first.) In this example, there are no elements before *w*, so we count 0.

After *w*, we only count the *h*'s, since these are moved to the front of the queue. There is only 1 in this example.

Finally, we count the number of *e*'s after the last *h* after *w* (if there is any *h* after *w*), since *w* is moved behind these *e*'s. There are 3, so in total we have 4 print-jobs before our own. Adding our own print-job, we get five jobs / minutes in total.

To do this, we need to look through the list twice, once to find the last *h* and once to do the counting.

EDIT:

With a new example. Let us assume that our queue is 2, 2', 9, 8, 2, 1, 7, where 2' is our document.

The first thing that happens is that the first 2 is sent to the back of the queue, followed by 2':

```
2 2' 9 8 2 1 7
2' 9 8 2 1 7 2
9 8 2 1 7 2 2'
```

Then the 9 and 8 are printed, leaving us with 2, 1, 7, 2, 2'. Now 2 and 1 are sent to the back.

```
2 1 7 2 2'
1 7 2 2' 2
7 2 2' 2 1
```

And 7 is printed. We are left with 2, 2', 2, 1. These are printed in order and 2' is printed as the 5th element overall.

If we follow the procedure above, we would rewrite this as:

```
2 2 9 8 2 1 7
e w h h e l h
```

Until *w*, we count 0 occurrences of *h* and 1 occurrence of *e*. This is the 2 which is later printed just before our own. After *w*, we count 3 *h*'s and 0 *e*'s after the last *h*. This means that there are three elements (9, 8 and 7) which will be printed before our own, while *e* and *l* (2 and 1) will not.

In total, we count 4 elements printed before our own and ours is the 5th.]]

I had not considered that elements could take several rounds. The above holds when the higher-priority jobs are in descending order, but a counterexample is (1’, 2, 1, 3) as ruakh pointed out.

Comment: The question was about calculating the time taken before one's own document was printed. The answer counts the number of other documents, so one should add 1 for the index of one's own job (or count it in the first run, I guess). And each document took 1 minute to print.

Comment: Sure but why 'add a minute for your own'?

Comment: Mmm, I meant, 'for your own [element]'. As in, 'add a minute to the calculated waiting time so far, to take the printing time of your own document into account'. Can you elaborate? I am new to this forum, should I expand/clarify the answer?

Comment: Can you show a step by step of how it works if the queue looked like this: 2 2(our job) 9 8 2 1 7

Comment: @user10729497 Sure - I have updated the reply with a new edit.

Comment: Don't understand why this was downvoted: it's correct.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Consider `1 2 1 3`. The second `1` gets printed before the first, but this answer thinks the first `1` gets printed before the second.